# Unable to stop React dev server using Ctrl+C in the terminal

Tags: node.js, reactjs, terminal

i've been always using the ctrl + C to end the node or react process not to close the terminal, just to finish the process running, but i don't know why, it's not working anymore

```
Compiled successfully!

You can now view game in the browser.

  Local:            http://localhost:3000
  On Your Network:  http://192.168.15.22:3000

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use npm run build.

webpack compiled successfully
^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C
```

Comment: What OS are you using? Did you try killing the process some other way like `pkill`, restarting the terminal, then re-running it to confirm the problem isn't a one-off?

Comment: @ggorlen i tried now, but still not working the Ctrl + C, and i'm using the 10.13.6 OS

Comment: Same issue here, Windows 10, create-react-app using react 18.2.0, react-scripts 5.0.1 and node 16.20.0 - I've got many other create-react-app working using everything from react 16 to 17 and no issues. This latest one I've downloaded and installed appears to be the issue. It's running fine, real-time compiles etc, just not picking up the Ctrl + C command in the terminal.

Comment: Adding to my comment above. I had package.json open in an editor while trying to stop the application. The moment I closed package.json I was able to use Ctrl + C command successfully. Don't know if that was coincidence of that may help anyone.